# Rubiks Cube Timer written in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer, rubiks-cube

I am a big fan of cubing, but I use Linux and can't find any decent timers. I tried to write one in python 3, but I haven't done is in years and it keeps drawing random errors. If says that the keyboard module doesn't exist. Could someone help.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import keyboard

loop
if keyboard.is_pressed ("space"):

    now=0
    do=true

    while do==True:
        now=now+1
        time.sleep(1000) #wait a second  before adding another secondtop your time. 

        if keyboard.is_pressed("space"):
            do=False

write(now)
if False:
    break
```

Comment: `keyboard` isn't a standard module afaik. Run `pop install keyboard`.

Comment: I tried that in Terminal just now, and I got a message saying "Command 'pop' not found, but there are 17 similar ones." On an unrelated note, could I make it add 0.01 to now, but only wait 0.01 seconds? That would give me far more accuracy and I see no reason that it wouldn't work.

Comment: That should be `pip install keyboard`. `pop` was a swypo.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll try that now.

Comment: It says that ```pip install keyboard```  is wrong, but it told me to try ```sudo apt install python-pip

Comment: Oh, ya, you need pip first. I assumed you had it already. Install it, then run that again.

Comment: It says that it was successfully installed. Thanks.

Comment: Keyboard or pip? If the first, try your code again.

Comment: I already installed pip, it said that keyboard was successfully installed.

Comment: Are there any edits I need to make to the Python program, because it is still drawing an error on ```Import Keyboard```